# Trying to read data from the fourth column in c# - unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to color some clusters with different colors based on the name assigned to the fourth column of the csv dataset.

this is how the dataset looks like:

```
0.4601581   0.5122409   0.4826243   Cluster_2
0.4718494   0.4834378   0.4433978   Cluster_3
0.4695727   0.4993355   0.4738764   Cluster_1
```

I am displaying in unity the first three columns in a cube but want to color the datapoints according to the fourth column.

I have tried this so far:

```
var cellValue = data.Rows[i][3];

if(cellValue=="Cluster_1")
{
    datapointMaterial.SetColor("_Color", new Color(0, 0, 1, 0.2f));
}
```

and this:

```
if (!myReader.EndOfStream && hasHeader)
{
    string[] header = myReader.ReadLine().Split(separator);

    if(header == "Cluster_1")
    {
        datapointMaterial.SetColor("_Color", new Color(0, 0, 1, 0.2f));
    }
    else
    {
        datapointMaterial.SetColor("_Color", new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.4f));    
    }
}
```

with this one I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `string[]`

any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This line here contains two errors: `if (header = "Cluster_1")`. First, this is not an equality comparison as you intended. Second, even if you fix it to be an equality comparision, then you would still try to compare a string with an array, which doesn't make sense...

Comment: I saw your edit. Okay, you fixed the equality comparison operator. But you are still trying to compare an array with a string, which is not really making sense...

Comment: @elgonzo yes true. Any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion? Yes, of course: Don't compare an array with a string ;-) Compare the two things you actually want to compare for equality, no?

Comment: @elgonzo well, I got that but how do I do that in my case?

Comment: How do what? What two things exactly do you want to compare? Okay, one thing is the string literal `"Cluster_1"`, obviously. What is the other thing to be compared against this string? An element from the header array? If so, which one? I can't tell you, i can only speculate... Only you yourself can answer your own question...

Comment: if(header[3] == "Cluster_1"){